# Minimizing Query String Using Mod ReWrite and HTAccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I've been wondering over the past few days about if it was possible to use Mod ReWrite to remove the variable section of a query string and leave just the value in the URL.

For example:    www.example.com/?page=firstpage could become www.example.com/?firstpage

While, I know through all intents and purposes it is an ugly url to look at, I merely wondered if it was possible to achieve through the HTACCESS file using Mod Rewrite.

I do know that I would have to use regex to achieve this and escape the question mark, but I'll admit that this particular problem has always outfoxed me.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule to make it possible

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.example.com/?%1 [R=301,L]`

It will redirect http://www.example.com/?page=firstpage to
http://www.example.com/?firstpage

For internal rewriting you can use this rules

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\?([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]`